# how to use variable in spring annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, spring-annotations

You are using the Pageable object provided by Spring, and you need to display this object through swagger. I am using Custom Annotation.
I want to change the size value of @ApiImplicitParam according to the ApiPageable Annotation variable.

Please refer to the picture below.
[image]

Comment: `@ApiImplicitParam` is not a Spring annotation but a Swagger annotation. You cannot inject values in it like that

Comment: Annotations can't inject compile time variables, even constants, their values must be hardcoded

Comment: @NicoVanBelle
The conclusion seems impossible. Thanks for your reply.